# Is $f(x,y)=f(x,y,t)$ if $x$ and $y$ are both function of t?

Tags: calculus

I saw this equation$$S(q)=\int_a^bL(t,q(t),\dot q(t))dt$$
in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).

So I would think that $f(x,y)$ must be equal to $f(x,y,t)$ if $x$ and $y$ are the function of $t$. So let's take an experiment.

Firstly, just let $f = f(x,y)$, where $x = x(t)$, $y=y(t)$, so $f=f\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$

$$\cfrac{df}{dt}=\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cfrac{dx}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cfrac{dy}{dt}\qquad (1)$$

Secondly, since you all see that $f$ is actually also a function of $t$, so we have

$$f = f(x,y)=f(x,y,t)\qquad (2)$$

Now,

$$\cfrac{df}{dt}=\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cfrac{dx}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cfrac{dy}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}\cfrac{dt}{dt}\qquad (3)$$

$$\cfrac{df}{dt}=\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cfrac{dx}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cfrac{dy}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}\qquad (4)$$

Because it is always correct that $\cfrac{df}{dt}=\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$,

$$\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cfrac{dx}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cfrac{dy}{dt}=0\qquad (5)$$

Substitute (5) into (1),

$$\cfrac{df}{dt}=0\qquad (6)$$

This is not a correct outcome, since (6) are not always equal to zero for all cases.

So what's wrong???

Comment: If $f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables then $f(x,y,t)$ makes no sense. You seem to be thinking of a new function $F(t)$ given by $F(t)=f(x(t),y(t))$.

Comment: As I see that you are a new member of the forum, i would like to remember to you that you should accept one of the answers, the one you feel answered your question the better.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. Just click the tick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is the height of a hillside above sea level, and $(x(t),y(t))$ the latitude and longitude of your car. Then $\frac{df}{dt}$ is the rate you are going up and down because the road slopes up or down.
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is the amount the road is physically rising or falling, for example because of continental drift or because a mine below it collapsed.

Comment: So do you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$ if $f=f(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: Oh my god, thank you~

Comment: I hope you can also answer this, thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547619/if-f-fxs-yt-then-frac-partial-f-partial-t-0-is-wrong/3547623#3547623

Comment: If $f=5t^2$, please evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$. Is it $0$? Or $10t$?

Comment: It is $10t{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

> Because it is always correct that $\cfrac{df}{dt}=\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$,

No, that's not correct, at all. At least not in this context.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ means "the partial derivative of $f$, with respect to its third variable, which we happen to call $t$". If you have taken a function of $x$ and $y$, then let $x$ and $y$ be functions of $t$, and now see $f$ as a function of $x,y,t$, then the third variable doesn't really appear. So $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$.

$\frac{df}{dt}$ on the other hand, means "rewrite (or at least reconceptualize) $f$ as a function solely of the variable $t$, using that $x,y$ are functions of $t$, then differentiate with respect to this $t$."

These are completely different things.

Comment: Ok, thank you~~

Comment: I hope you can also answer this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547619/if-f-fxs-yt-then-frac-partial-f-partial-t-0-is-wrong/3547624#3547624

Answer (score 1):

If we write $f(x,y,t)$ we mean an *explicit* dependence of time. This makes the assertion you make

> Because it is always correct that $$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} $$

**incorrect**. Whenever there's an explicit dependence on time, the partial derivative takes it into account. Let's say for example that you have the following lagrangian

$$ L(x(t), y(t), t) = \frac{1}{2} m \left(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\right) - At$$ you can compute the total derivative of the lagrangian and see by yourself that indeed your assertion is wrong.

Physcally speaking we put the explicit dependence on time in the lagrangian because if there's some *dissipative* terms, they usually depende directly on time while, as well, the position depends on time. So the explicit dependence is made clear for this reasons, not because the position depends on time. That's an *implicit* dependence on time.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you

Comment: I hope you can also answer this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547619/if-f-fxs-yt-then-frac-partial-f-partial-t-0-is-wrong/3547624#3547624