# If $f=f(x(s),y(t))$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$ is wrong?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547384/is-fx-y-fx-y-t-if-x-and-y-are-both-function-of-t?noredirect=1#comment7294828_3547384)
You may see through the link that someone pointed out that if$$f=f(x(t),y(t))$$then$$\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$$So now i want to challenge this by giving an example:

Let $f=f(x,y)$, where $x=x(t)$,$y=y(s)$. Because $f$ is independent of $t$, so we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0\qquad(1)$$

Now, given that $x=x(t)=2t^2$, $y=y(s)=3s$, then f is given by:$$f=f(x,y)=xy\qquad(2)$$
Substitute $x=x(t)=2t^2$, $y=y(s)=3s$ into (2), we have$$f=6t^2s\qquad(3)$$It follows that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=12ts\qquad(4)$$Equation(1) and Equation (4) are not equal, what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not understanding what people said in answering your other question.

The root of your confusion is that you write things like $f=f(x(t), y(t)$ without making clear what this means.

The true story is that there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, say $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$.

Then there are two functions $x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, say $t\mapsto x(t)$: and $y:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, say $t\mapsto y(t)$.

From these we can form a **new** function, $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, given by $t\mapsto  F(t)=f(x(t), y(t))$. 
You can then sensibly partially differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$; differentiate each of $x$ and $y$ with respect to $t$;  and differentiate $F$ with respect to $t$.

The Chain Rule then says
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}.$$

**Warning**

It leads to endless confusion to use the same letter for both $f$ and $F$. I know that people do this, but they are confusing values with functions.

In the "example" you give you confuse things further by jumping from $f=f(x(t),y(t))$ to $f=f(x(s),y(t))$ as though this made any sense. Here you've got yet another function, $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(s,t)=f(x(s),y(t))$. Using the Chain Rule correctly will remove your confusions/supposed contradictions.

Comment: Oh my god, i completely understand now, so clear. But i still don’t know the value of (1) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ if $f=f(x(t),y(t))$, is it really zero?(2) $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ for $F(t)=f(x(t),y(t))$, is it also zero?

Comment: (1)$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ makes no sense. (2) $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ is just $\frac{d F}{d t}$, as there's only one variable, and in general it won't be zero.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is **not** independent of $t$.

$f$ depends on $x$ and $y$, both of which in turn depend on $t$. So $f$ depends on $t$.

Remember the chain rule:
$$f_t = f_xx_t +f_yy_t$$

Comment: Is it true that if $f=f(x(t),y(t))$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$?

Comment: Only if $f$ is constant

Answer (score 0):

$t$ affects $f$. in other words $f$ and $t$ is dependent since $f$=$f$($x$($s$),$y$($t$)) hope this helps! :)

Comment: When $f=5t^2$, please evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, is it zero? Or $10t$? thanks ^_^

Comment: I think you have not understood what i said,,maybe when you study more, you will be able to understand..However you can be more kind.

Comment: I am so sorry to let you feel i am rude, but i really want to know the answer of the question that i asked you. Also that i know completely what you have said, but i still confuse about the value of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$. I just know $\frac{df}{dt}$ = 10t. What about $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$?